# How to convert a string into an existing variable name of a list as a parameter of a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am looking for a way to convert a string into an existing variable name of a list, I am a beginner in this field and trying to develop a simple program and I encounter this kind of a problem I have, to summarize, I need to pass a parameter to function which is a string, and to that said function I need that parameter to be converted as a variable name so I can access the lists that has the same name as that string.

this is my code:

```
#datachart.py
datos = [0,100,100] #I need to access this and print it to another script


#main.py
from datachart import *

def data_send(usr):
    #Now the user input which is a string is now here as 'usr'
    #The problem is here, I cant access the lists from datachart cause 
    #using usr[0] will just take the character of a string.

    #somecode or something to turn usr into a recognizable variable name 
    #of a list from datachart which is named as datos to be able to do 
    #the code below:

    print("Coins: {} Tokens: {} Money: {}".format(usr[0],usr[1],usr[2]))

def send_val():
    usr = input("Username: ")

    # Consider "datos" as the value of user input.

    data_send(usr)

send_val()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign the list in `datachart.py` to the variable input in the `main.py`:

```
#datachart.py
datos = [0,100,100]

#main.py
from datachart import *

def data_send(usr):
    usr = datos        # assigned here
    print("Coins: {} Tokens: {} Money: {}".format(usr[0],usr[1],usr[2]))

def send_val():
    usr = input("Username: ")
    data_send(usr)

send_val()
```

**EDIT**:

Another way could be using [`getattr()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr):

> Return the value of the named attribute of object. name must be a
>   string. If the string is the name of one of the object’s attributes,
>   the result is the value of that attribute. For example, getattr(x,
>   'foobar') is equivalent to x.foobar. If the named attribute does not
>   exist, default is returned if provided, otherwise AttributeError is
>   raised.

```
#datachart.py
datos = [0,100,100]

#main.py
from datachart import *
import datachart

def data_send(usr):
    usr = getattr(datachart, usr, None)   # with None as a default val
    if usr:
       print("Coins: {} Tokens: {} Money: {}".format(usr[0],usr[1],usr[2]))

def send_val():
    usr = input("Username: ")
    data_send(usr)

send_val()
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
Username: datos
Coins: 0 Tokens: 100 Money: 100
```

> Note: I recommend the edited version

Comment: This works fine and really efficient, but what if I have more than one list in datachart.py not just datos. 

for example: 

#datachart.py
datos = [0,100,100]
datos2 = [100,50,34]
datos3 = [32,100,233]

Is there any way to specifically call these lists on data_send? or its ideal to just use dictionary if it that somehow works.

Comment: @Sorcuris  you could check with the user input in your send_val() method, then pass that string input to getattr() method and if it exists in the datacharts.py it would return the list.

Comment: It works fine, might use the getatt for another functions which is appending values to an specific list.

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly do that using the globals() builtin method.

```py
# file1
datos = [0,100,100]
```

```py
from file1 import *

print(dict(globals())['datos'])
```

> **globals()** Returns a dictionary representing the current global symbol table. This is always the dictionary of the current module (inside a function or method, this is the module where it is defined, not the module from which it is called).

Read more in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals)

Answer (score 1):

In python 2 I find your code to be working fine

In python 3, since input is converted to string instead of accessing variables inside the code, you need to use `globals()` to access back variable list.

Note that, this is only for the purpose of exercising, using a dict instead of accessing variable directly is prefered, because such behavior is unsafe from a security standpoint.

```py
def data_send(usr):
    try:
        usr = globals()[usr]
    except KeyError:
        return # Handle case the user inputs a non-existing variable the best you can
    print("Coins: {} Tokens: {} Money: {}".format(usr[0],usr[1],usr[2]))
```

Answer (score -2):

[Python dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) would be suitable for this use case. Essentially all possible parameter values would become keys in the dictionary `chart_data`.

```
chart_data = {
   "dataos": [0,100,100]
}

#main.py
from datachart import *

def data_send(usr):
    print("Coins: {} Tokens: {} Money: {}".format(chart_data[usr][0],chart_data[usr][1],chart_data[usr][2]))

def send_val():
    usr = input("Username: ")
    data_send(usr)

send_val()
```

Comment: Not really, you changed the list to a dict, not sure if that is acceptable.

Comment: @DirtyBit leave that to the the person who asked the question to decide.